# Why my regex does not match the 'username' constraints

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to write a regex on code camp which must fit the following 4 constraints defined for a correct 'username'

1) Usernames can only use alpha-numeric characters.

2) The only numbers in the username have to be at the end. There can be zero or more of them at the end. Username cannot start with the number.

3) Username letters can be lowercase and uppercase.

4) Usernames have to be at least two characters long. A two-character username can only use alphabet letters as characters.

Here is the Regex I came up with, in the following code (first line)

```
let userCheck = /[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]+\d*|\d\d+)/; // the regex I wrote
let result = userCheck.test(username);
```

However, it displays the following fault

```
Your regex should not match BadUs3rnam3
Your regex should not match c57bT3
```

I am absolutely confused. I actually know what the correct regex to this problem is, however, I need to know where my own regex is going wrong which is producing the above error. Please help

Comment: Thank you @JvdV!  although I have no idea why but adding the end and start strings solved the problem. I changed  my regex to > `/ ^[a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z]+\d*$ | \d\d+$)/`

Comment: No problem @Maryam, I removed my comment/answer as it's now fully covered in the remaining answer =). Btw, without ancors you allow your pattern to start matching mid-string, negating the fact you want to look at the **whole** string > `^.....$` to look at everything in between. Don't forget to accept the answer below either.

Comment: ah, I got it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code passes because you are not using anchors so you get a partial match.

You could update the pattern to `^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z]+\d*|\d{2,})$`

Another way to write it could be matching either 2 chars a-zA-Z and 0+ digits, or in case there is a single char a-zA-Z, match 2 or more digits to pass the rule
*A two-character username can only use alphabet letters as characters.*

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,}\d*|[a-zA-Z]\d{2,})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zs3UJO/2)

```js
let userCheck = /^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z]+\d*|\d{2,})$/;
[
  "BadUs3rnam3",
  "c57bT3",
  "aa",
  "a111111",
  "a1",
  "11"
].forEach(username => console.log(username + ": " + userCheck.test(username)));
```

Comment: I forgot about a 3-char case with 2 digits end. Nice =)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is on free Code Camp and i have also attempted this one with the help of the hit given by them which suggests this as the solution

```
let username = "JackOfAllTrades";
let userCheck = /^[a-z][a-z]+\d*$|^[a-z]\d\d+$/i;
let result = userCheck.test(username);
console.log(result)
```

but in my opinion the above regex pattern does not conform to the fourth condition that is given in the question which is

> Usernames have to be at least two characters long. A two-character username can only use alphabet letters as characters.

Comment: The first option in their regex is conforming, and the second requires 3 characters so its not. First optional is `^[a-z][a-z]+\d*$`the first `[a-z]` group matches the 1st letter only. The second `[a-z]+` group starts matching at the second letter since the first letter is already matched, it has the + modifier, so it is matched 1+ times, the `\d*` means this is followed by 0+ digits. The 2nd condition of the regex is `[a-z]\d\d+` the `[a-z]` group forces first letter only to be a character, \d matches the 2nd digit, and the \d+ matches 3rd or more digits `[a-z]\d+` or `[a-z]\d\d*` would solve